# Proving that function with domain (-1,1) is injective.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Function $g\colon (-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is defined by $g(x)=\dfrac{x}{1-x^2}$. Prove that $g(x)$ is injective.

Work:

I shifted the equation so that it ends up like $\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{1-x^2}{1-y^2}$. From here, I thought about using cases such as $x>y$ or $y>x$ to prove it, but it does not seem to work. I tried to manipulate the equation into various forms, but I cannot end up with $x=y$.

Comment: It's not mandatory, but it advisable and doing so will motivate people to answer your questions. You can go to your old questions and accept them, if you wish.

Comment: Ok, I went back and accepted the answers that helped me. However, I don't want to post a duplicate question and nobody seems to be answering this one.

Comment: Since you were a good boy, I'll help you $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x,y\in (-1,1)$. Note that $x\neq 0\implies \dfrac 1 x\not \in (-1,1)$, (this will be useful).

Now note that
$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac x{1-x^2}=\dfrac y{1-y^2} &\implies x(1-y^2)=y(1-x^2)\\
&\implies x-xy^2=y-x^2y\\
&\implies x^2y+x=y+xy^2\\
&\implies x(xy+1)=y(xy+1)\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\vdots 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks!That was very helpful. The other answer was too.

Comment: You're welcome. I often recommend not to hurry in accepting answers. An answer being accepted will motivate people to *not* give new answers. And among the new answers might come one which you like better.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your function as follows $f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} - x}$

Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$. That is

$$ \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} - x} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{y} - y}  \iff  \frac{\frac{1}{y}-y}{\frac{1}{x} - x} = 1$$

We want to show $x = y$. Suppose not. Then we either have $x > y$ or $y > x$.

Suppose $y > x$. Then $-y < -x $ and $\frac{1}{y} < \frac{1}{x} $. Hence

$$ 1 =  \frac{\frac{1}{y}-y}{\frac{1}{x} - x} <  \frac{\frac{1}{x}-x}{\frac{1}{x} - x} = 1$$

Contradiction!

Similarly, I let you do it the case $x  > y$ which will lead you to a contradiction.

Therefore $x = y$ which implies $f$ is injective